# Plesk not sending mail to domain with google apps

Tags: php, plesk

I have a domain setup in Plesk 11. On this domain I want to send an e-mail to an e-mail address which is the same domain as the domain it is being send from. (Via php mailer) but this doesn't work. I turned off the plesk mail service, checkked the DNS in plesk but it still doesn't work. When sending it to a @gmail.com address it does work. What could possibly go wrong?

=========

I solved this by using PHPMailer

Answer (score 2):

Tuen off mail server in plesk for your domain
check DNS entries for your domain
also check via the same www.intodns.com you all MX record going to google app so it's file.

Some time google mx record will take 48 hours to update the cache at there end.

note : make sure turn off mail server on domain per following link :
https://manage.grabweb.net/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=748

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configure your MX to point to Gmail Mail Server?
Check this link, maybe can help you
http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=140034